# Adding a new font for BIRT Reporting

Tags: birt

I need to add a new font type for one of my reports, Monotype Corsiva. How do i do that in BIRT? My BIRT version is 3.7.2. I have both the ttf and otf files.

Comment: OP is asking if he can bundle fonts with his BIRT application. For example if he develops on a Windows machine and uses the Veranda font, but deploys to a linux machine it will not be available. Without having to manually install Veranda on any server he wishes to run his application from, can fonts simply be placed somewhere inside the application and referenced?

Answer (score 5):

After playing around my localhost, this is what i did:

1. go to eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.fonts_3.7.2.v20120213/fontsConfig.xml
2. add in new font path
3. restart the laptop

But i do not like this way of doing it, cos it is crude, and i need to upload it to the server too. How do i go about doing that?

Comment: This looks like it should be placed as an edit to the question not as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you are you asking how to add a font to BIRT, or how to have a specic font displayed when the report is deployed.

If when deployed are they PDF, HTML, Excel, etc?

This tip descripes how to make many changes to the font and style at run time  http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/1200-set-fontstyle-information-on-a-report-using-de-api-or-script/

It can be done in the ElementFactory with

```
  dataStyle.setProperty( StyleHandle.FONT_FAMILY_PROP, "Monotype Corsiva"
```

Or in the beforeFactory with

```
 reportContext.getDesignHandle().findStyle("report").setProperty(StyleHandle.FONT_FAMILY_PROP, "Monotype Corsiva");
```

Of course for both of these the font would need to be available on the PC running the report.

Comment: Hi James, they will be deployed to a pdf file.

Comment: When you create the report as PDF the PDF will need access to the fonts also. There is a good right up here http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/28406-fonts-rendered-different-when-generating-pdf-report/ about making fonts render in PDF when there is a problem.